# D3.JS SVG Дискретный фильтр изображений

Tags: svg, изображения, d3.js, фильтры

```js
var svg, defs, pattern;

svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 192).attr("height", 192);

svg.append("rect").attr("width", 192).attr("height", 192).attr("fill", "#DEDEDE");

var defs = defs = svg.append("svg:defs");

var bw_bitmap = "data:image/png;base64,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";

var ptrn = defs.append("svg:pattern")
  .attr("id", "raster")
  .attr("width", 128)
  .attr("height", 128)
  .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
  .attr("patternTransform", "translate(32,32)")
  .append("svg:image")
  .attr("xlink:href", bw_bitmap)
  .attr("width", 128)
  .attr("height", 128)
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0);

var filtered = svg.append("rect").attr("x", 32).attr("y", 32).attr("width", 128).attr("height", 128)
  .attr("fill", "url(#raster)").attr("filter", "url(#discrete)");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
      
    <filter id="discrete" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
        <feComponentTransfer>
            <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
            <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
            <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
        </feComponentTransfer>
        <feComponentTransfer>
            <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.486 1.0 0.937"/>
            <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.812 1.0 0.360"/>
            <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.847 1.0 0.125"/>
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
      
    <filter id="gradiental" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
        <feComponentTransfer>
            <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.486 1.0 0.937"/>
            <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.812 1.0 0.360"/>
            <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.847 1.0 0.125"/>
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
      
  </defs>
</svg>
```

На английском StackOverflow мне никто не смог помочь, может в русском сегменте помогут.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть произвольное PNG изображение, где голубой это -1, белый 0, а оранжевый 1.0. Проще говоря это визуализация двумерного массива данных в области -1 ... 1.

Необходимо разработать SVG дисретный фильтр, который бы все значение от -1 до 0 показывал одним голубым тоном, 0 до 1 оранжевым.

Решение должно быть только в виде SVG фильтра, остальные методы не интересуют.

Пока мне удалось сделать нечто похожее, но если исходное изображение черно-белое, где промежуточный 'нулевой' цвет #808080.

Ссылка на оригинальную картинку https://yadi.sk/i/jE5RE7ktbF1IVw (PNG, 128x128)

[image]

Comment: Это можно сказать искуственная задача, для саморазвития так сказать. Поэтому нужно решение именно на SVG фильтрах.

Comment: D3.JS основана на SVG, тащить в нее шейдеры конечно можно, но нужно именно то что описал. Тем более производительность не нужна.

Comment: Одним, но самым жирным 

Comment: Я с Вами особо и не спорю. Более того, если Вам не трудно, можете выложить сюда пример со стэком D3/WebGL/GLSL. Может кому-то пригодится такая альтернатива.

Comment: Если формально, то меня текущий вариант устраивает. Хранить все в черно-белом формате, а просто менять два фильтра—discrete и gradiental. Но для саморазвития хотелось бы знать как из левого получить правый (см иллюстрацию) без трюка с черно-белой версией. Не должно быть сложно, но вчера, просматривая документацию ко мне SVG «примочкам», не нашёл ничего подходящего.

Comment: Вставил в вопрос

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/BgpPaW

Comment: Альфа канал не нужен совсем. Может JPG опубликовать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95195/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-vvk).

Answer (score 2):

Поколдовал с `feColorMatrix`, вот изображения до и после

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Как это работает:

**первый фильтр:**

1. извлекает значения красного канала и вычитает из него 95%, соответственно в красном канале остается только область где было много красного.
2. умножает значение зеленого канала на -1 и прибавляет 60%, соответственно в зеленом канале остается область где было зеленого меньше чем 40%

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**второй фильтр:**

многократно увеличивает значения в красном и зеленом канале, в итоге получается изображение в котором одна область красно-зелено-желтая а вторая черная

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**третий фильтр:**

делает черную область серой (0.5 во всех каналах), а цветную белой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**четвертый фильтр:**

меняет черный цвет на цвет A и белый цвет на цвет B

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<img src="https://imgur.com/SD4DxlF.png">
<img src="https://imgur.com/SD4DxlF.png" style="filter:url(#f)">
<svg>
    <defs>
        <filter id="f">
            <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="
                  1  0 0 0 -0.95   
                  0 -1 0 0  0.6
                  0  0 0 0  0 
                  0  0 0 1  0" result="f1" />
            <feColorMatrix in="f1" type="matrix" values="
                  111111 0      0 0 0   
                  0      111111 0 0 0  
                  0      0      0 0 0 
                  0      0      0 1 0" result="f2"/>
            <feColorMatrix in="f2" type="matrix" values="
                  1 1 1 0 0.5   
                  1 1 1 0 0.5  
                  1 1 1 0 0.5 
                  0 0 0 1 0" result="f3"/>
            <feComponentTransfer in="f3">
                <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.5 0.490 0.937"/>
                <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.5 0.812 0.360"/>
                <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.5 0.847 0.125"/>
            </feComponentTransfer>
        </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ну тоже не идеальное решение. 1. Есть небольшой артефакт на большем разрешении https://yadi.sk/i/-Zhqv4Pw9H_yHg (голубая полоса). 2. Цвета не совпадают, при том что их пересчитал с большей точностью. Первый пункт весьма критичен. Так что скорее всего остановлюсь на своем варианте. Все равно огромное спасибо.

Comment: @VVK из -а такой палитры сложно разделить цвета фильтром...

Comment: @VVK полосу я могу поправить, нарерное, а вот то что граница немного сдвинута - вряд ли. для другой палитры, где каждый из 2х цветов не является смешением всех 3х каналов все будет достаточно точно

Comment: @VVK а есть картинка хайрез, я бы подкрутил этот фильтр

Comment: Как раз в задаче картинки еще меньше, 16x16, даже 8x8. И паттерн, как Вы понимаете, всегда разный.

Comment: @VVK да, естественно, но я поленился генерировать тестовые изображения, я тут подумал и получается что потери примерно пропорциональны тому, насколько цвета ближе друг другу в сумме по всем каналам, грубо говоря сверху и снизу от линии градиенты неразличимы очень близко к линии